# need help bootstrap 3 button style

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this error in the style of bootstrap 3 buttons and need help

i make a small game in html, css,bootstrap.jquery and json file

the question start ok
[image]

this the initial window if the user click the right answer this happen
[image]

can any one help me how to fix this issue!!

i try this.blur();
i try a lot of change in css but not fix this the CSS i work with

```
.btn-default,
.btn-default.active:focus,
.btn-default.active.focus {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fc9c36 0,#8e3016 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fc9c36 0,#8e3016 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#fc9c36),to(#8e3016));
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fc9c36 0,#8e3016 100%);
    color: white;
    font-size: large;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

    .btn-default.active:hover,
    .btn-default:active:hover {
        color: white;
        background-color: #8e3016;
        border-color: #fc9c36;
    }

    .btn-default:focus{
        outline:0 !important;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Bassem, we aren't a discussion forum and your comment below shouldn't have been posted as an answer. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Here's a demo which does not show your problem. Please see if you can modify it to do so, then we can look into it. https://jsfiddle.net/qbtjcmdL/